# Is there a way to create a unique event handler for each user. | Python discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py

Im trying to create a python discord bot where it has a registration process.
Trouble is, right now if 2 people are registering at the same time. The bot only binds to one users channel and the other stops working. Is there a way that I can create a unique event handler and test if the user is the user registering and then do it that way. Because Im out of ideas

Comment: provide current code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.